# How to add the returned result of a function to a file being written too in C++?

Tags: c++, ofstream

Hello Im currently writting a program that reads data on a text file, performs calculations, and then ouputs the results to a output text file

This is the program in full

main file

```
int main() {

readFile(inputFile1, inputFile2, inputFile3, lines);
robotComplexity(lines);
robotVariability(lines);
writeFile(outputFile, lines, robotComplexity(lines), robotVariability(lines));

getch();
return 0;

}

void Customer() {
std::string customerName;
std::string projectName;
std::string partNumber;;
}

void Parts() {

char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;

}
void Builder() {

std:string name;
int ability;
int variability;

}
```

Implentation file

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string inputFile1 = "Builders.txt";
std::string inputFile2 = "Parts.txt";
std::string inputFile3 = "Customers.txt";
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

void readFile(std::string const& inputFile1, std::string const& inputFile2, std::string const& inputFile3,
              std::vector<std::string>& lines) //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
   std::ifstream file1(inputFile1);
   std::ifstream file2(inputFile2);
   std::ifstream file3(inputFile3);
   std::string line;

   while(std::getline(file1, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

     while(std::getline(file2, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

     while(std::getline(file3, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

}


double robotComplexity(std::vector<std::string>& lines) { //takes in the out.txt file

std::string output = lines[0]; //so far only reads the first line of the output file. 
std::string input = output.substr(18,1);

double complexity = 20 * atoi(input.c_str());


   if(complexity > 100) {
      complexity = 100;
   }

cout << "The Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
return complexity;
}

double robotVariability(std::vector<std::string>& lines) {

std::string output = lines[0]; //so far only reads the first line of the output file. 
std::string input = output.substr(15,2);

double variability;

variability = 5 + atoi(input.c_str());

cout << "The Robot Variability is: " << variability << endl;
return variability;

}

void writeFile(std::string const& outputFile,
               std::vector<std::string> const& lines, double unitComplexity, double unitVariability) //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations. 
{
   std::ofstream file(outputFile);
   for(std::string const& line: lines)
   {
      file << line << std::endl;
   }

   for(double x: unitComplexity) {
      file << x << std::endl;
   }


}
```

The code I'd like to draw attention too is the last 3 functions in the implementation file, being robotCompelxity, robotVariability and writeFile. The first 2 functions pefrom calculations based on the file that was read and writeFile, to this point in time, contains the details of each robot as seen in the main file(IE, builder, customers and parts) This works and details are outputted successfully to the file.

My issue lies with the robotVariability and the robotComplexity Functions. As seen in the writeFile funtions paramaters, in takes in a string const which is the output file, a vector list which is the robot details, and two doubles, being the results of the robotVariability and robotComplexity Functions. I've attempted to create an enhanced for loop to add such results to the output file, seen in this line of code at the end

```
for(double x: unitComplexity) {
      file << x << std::endl;
   }
```

However, this causes an error to be read denoted by "this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found". Im unsure on how to resolve this issue.

To reiterate, Im simply trying to add the results of both robotComplexity and robotVariability both being of type double, to the file that is being writen to in the writeFile function. Thankyou.

Comment: `unitComplexity` is passed to the function as a `double`  i.e. a single value.   The range-based for is for iterating over elements of a container (e.g. a vector, a list).  A `double` is not a container.   Since your `robotComplexity()` and `robotVariability()` both return a `double`, their return value can be passed to `unitComplexity()` - but they are still not containers.   Try replacing the loop with a single output statement, such as `file << unitComplexity << std::end1`.

Comment: Thankyou! I was honestly so confused as to why it wasnt accept the loop as a double but this clears it up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to output the doubles without the ranged for-loop like this

```
void writeFile(std::string const& outputFile,
               std::vector<std::string> const& lines, double unitComplexity, double unitVariability) //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations. 
{
   std::ofstream file(outputFile);
   for(std::string const& line: lines)
   {
      file << line << std::endl;
   }

   file << unitComplexity << std::endl;
   file << unitVariability << std::endl;
}
```

And the function will write the doubles to the text file. Ranged for-loops only best with objects like vectors and arrays, not single value variables.

Comment: Thankyou it works! Another side question, in my main i declare robotComplexity and robotVariability twice, once on their own and then again as paramaters for the writeFile function, thus it prints twice. Should i simply remove the first time i call them?